# How to set z-index in css?

Tags: html, css

I am unable to set z-index. would you please define me, how to set z-index position or values ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp - A simple Google Search yields me this. If you are looking for something specific to z-index, please edit your question likewise.

Comment: w3fools FTW. P.s. check the position of your elements before setting z-index ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code and example to try:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Just enter the test value for z-index and other properties and test immediately how it behave.

**Added more info**

z-index for image is defined as below:

```
img
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:-1;
}
```

There are two thing which you can modify with respect to z-index:

```
position: absolute  | relative | fixed
z-index: +ve | -ve value from -9999 to 9999
```

In the above example you can change the values in real time to see the effect which will help you to understand it much better.

Answer (score 2):

z-index : [some number];

You have to use absolute or relative positioning for it to take effect though

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` works only on positioned elements.  Maybe you didn't apply `position` property and gave it a `z-index` try

```
<style type="text/css">
.myelement{
    position:relative; /*You can put position relative absolute or fixed for z-index to work*/
    z-index:100;
}
</style>
```

For further reference refer this page
[W3Schools Page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score -1):

For Divs:

```
#yourdiv {
 z-index: 9999 ; //whatever the value you want
}
```

For Class:

```
.class {
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain me what is different values means ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex
Try it here by changing the z-index of img. You will know the difference. 
Credits to AvkashChauhan for the link.